# What is a FAT header?

Tags: tools

Today I saw a command line option in the output of **otool** (this is a MacOS X program, offering similar functionality as `objdump`) that is named:

```
-f -- print the fat headers
```

So, what are the **fat headers** ?

I tried to Google '*fat headers*' and '*fat headers elf*' but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fat header is the header of a fat binary.

See [pages 67-68 in *Mac OS X Internals*](http://books.google.com/books?id=K8vUkpOXhN4C&pg=PA67):

> Note that a fat binary is essentially a *wrapper*—a simple archive that
>   concatenates Mach-O files for multiple architectures. A fat binary
>   begins with a fat header (`struct fat_header`) that contains a magic number followed by an integral value representing the number of architectures whose binaries reside in the fat binary.
>
> ...
>
> [image: fat header]